# How to send data from frontend to backend securely?

Tags: javascript, flask, jwt

I want to implement comments to my blog and I want to use javascript to do it. When searching for this on stackoverflow I find answers that seem somewhat years old and uses ajax. I figure that javascript must've evolved since then and so I am looking for a modern approach.

How do I send the users' comment from a textarea to flask backend with javascript and including appropriate security (i.e. JWT)?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has evolved, but it still doesn't have any kind of IO functionalities, everything is up to the environment the JS is run in. AJAX is still in use, if that feels old-fashion, take a look at [old stuff in a new wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).